# What does '3 .column.size-1of3' do inside ::before content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to setup the [salvattore](http://salvattore.com/) plugin to arrange elements on a page.

Our project uses slim and ruby on rails:

Here is the html structure

```
div id="grid" datacolumns=""
    = render @foo
```

Here is _foo.html.slim

```
div 
    |Some Text Here
```

The plugin page says doing this will suffice:

```
#grid[data-columns]::before {
    content: '3 .column.size-1of3';
}

.column { float: left; }
.size-1of3 { width: 33.333%; }
```

But, the before element isn't showing up on the page. I understand ::before is a pseudo class and content is the content that is added.

But, what I don't understand is how does '3 .column.size-1of3' translate to html and why it isn't working.

Comment: Isn't there a bit of Javascript that scans the data-columns elements for generated content and applies the content as classes to the grid?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be. Which is why I am curious if content does more than simply inserting it's value before the selected element.